# $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{12^n(2-x_n)}{C}=1$ for $x_n=\sqrt[3]{6+x_{n-1}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponentiation, radicals

> **Problem:** Assume we have the next recursive sequence:
>   $$\begin{cases}x_n=\sqrt[3]{6+x_{n-1}}\\x_1 = \sqrt[3]{6}\end{cases}$$
>   Prove that there exists a constant $C \neq 0$ such that:
>   $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{12^n(2-x_n)}{C}=1$$

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: That seems a rather weird and obfuscated way to say.  $\lim 12^n(2 - x_n) = c \ne 0$.

Comment: Did you see that $xn\rightarrow2 \text{ for }n\rightarrow \infty$ ? Work from there.

Comment: Yes, but what to do after that?

Comment: Note $2 > x_n > x_{n-1}$ and $2 - x_n < 12^{-n}$.

Comment: $(2-x_n)12^n < 12^{-n}12^n = 1$ so the sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider $x_0=0$ as the starting term (this is prettier) .

Let's prove that $x_n$ converges to $2$ monotonically increasing .

Inductively $x_n <2 $ because :

$1)$ $x_0<2$

$2)$ Assuming that $x_n<2$ then $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{x_n+6}<\sqrt[3]{8}=2$

Now let's prove that $x_{n+1}>x_n$ .
This is equivalent with : 
$$x_n^3<x_n+6$$ or after factoring :

$$(x_n-2)(x_n^2+2x_n+3)<0$$ which is obvious because $x_n<2$ .

The sequence is thus bounded above by $2$ and increasing so it converges to a number $a$ .

Now let $n \to \infty $ in the recurrence so :

$$a_3=a+6$$
$$(a-2)(a^2+2a+3)=0$$
$$a=2$$

This means that $x_n$ converges to $2$ .

Note that the recurrence can be rewritten as :

$$8-x_{n+1}^3=2-x_n$$

Now let $y_n=2-x_n$ and also $z_n=x_n^2+2x_n+4$ so  :
$$y_{n+1}z_{n+1}=y_n$$

Now iterate this :
$$y_{n}z_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot z_n=y_0=2$$

It's obvious that $z_n$ converges to $12$ .Let $a_n=\frac{z_n}{12}$ so $a_n$ converges to $1$ .

Also : $$12^ny_n=\frac{2}{a_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n}$$

The product is strictly decreasing (because $a_n<1$ ) and bounded between $0$ and $1$ .So it must converge to a number $A$.

Then $C=\frac{2}{A}$ is the number you're looking for .

Comment: How are we sure that $12^n y_n \not\to 0$? This proves that $12^ny_n$ converges to some $l\in [0,1]$

Comment: you haven't rule out the possibilities that $A = 0$. in any event, this already worth an upvote.

Comment: @user160738, the product $\prod_{k=1}^n a_k$ is decreasing, so $12^n y_n$ is increasing and $\not\to 0$.

Comment: @achillehui ah, right, thanks for that :)